# Minimize error function with integer constraints

Tags: algorithms, optimization, integer-programming

Much time has passed since I studied any form of math so I wanted to take this cheap shot of asking someone else to think for me.

I need to write some software that, for any given real number argument y between 0.0 and 510.0 (approximated by a float) finds two natural numbers h and m (expressed as integers between 0-255) that minimise the difference between y and h * m / 128.

I think that the following code is a brute force solver of the problem but it is excruciatingly inefficient:

`function errFunc (y, h, m)
{
    return Math.abs (y - (h * m / 128.0));
}
function fit (y)
{
    var minError = 2; // y <= 510, h <= 255, h <= 255. So errFunc(y) < 2 
    var h;
    var m;
    for (h = 0; h < 256; h++)
    {
        for (m = 0; m < 256; m++)
        {
            e = errFunc (y, h, m);
        if (e < minError)
            {
                minError = e;
                optimalH = h;
                optimalM = m;
            }
        }
    }
}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to reexamine the requirement that you need two integers $h$ and $m$. If you really just need an integer $k$ that makes $k/128$ as close to $y$ as possible, then $k$ is either $N$ or $N+1$ (where $N=\lfloor 128y\rfloor$), depending on whether $y$ is in the left half or the right half of $[\frac{N}{128},\frac{N}{128}+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying all combinations of $h$ and $m$ values you could loop through all the possible $h$ and try just $m=\left\lfloor \frac{128y}{h} +\frac12 \right\rfloor$ for each of them.

You'll need to special-case $h=0$, but zeroes will be involved if and only if $y\le\frac1{256}$, so you can handle that once and for all at the beginning.

You can optimize further by trying only $h$ in the interval $1$ to $\Bigl\lfloor \sqrt{128y}\Bigr\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=128y$ and assume $k \lt 128y$ (you will have to test, and the update should be obvious).  Then let $p=\text{int}(k)$
Test in order $p,p+1,p-1,p+2,p-2\dots$ for being able to be factored into two numbers less than $255$
Having a list of primes up to $255$ will make the factorization quick.  If there is a factor greater than $255$ you fail and go on to the next one.

The hard part comes with numbers like $y=229.46$  We get $p=29391=3\cdot 97 \cdot 101$, which has no factors greater than $255$, but cannot be split into two factors less than $255$.   If $p$ has lots of factors it will be easy, otherwise you may have to search all the combinations.

Comment: I doubt the overhead of trying to be smart with factoring and such will be worth it rather than simply brute-forcing up to 255 tries.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  for these numbers I suspect you are right.